# Issue With Not plotting graph if datasource having same data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm facing a problem with plotting data using the CorePlot framework. I have [integrated it](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) and below there's a sample of my code from the project I'm working on: live scatter
chart.

If my data sources have the same values then graph is not plotting.

This is the code for plotting points:

```
#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [appDelegate.arrayLiveValues count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum 
                                       recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSInteger valueCount = [appDelegate.arrayLiveValues count];
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < valueCount) {
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            return [appDelegate.arrayLiveValues  objectAtIndex:index];
            break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

If `appDelegate.arrayLiveValues` array contains duplicate values then it's not plotting. If it have different values it's plotting the graph, based on values in `datasource`, i.e. `appDelegate.arrayLiveValues` the graph zoom level is setting.
I want to know the what's the inner functionality

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index method;
```

Comment: Assuming `arrayLiveValues` is an array of numbers, this looks fine. How are you scaling the plot space?

Comment: if the array contains same number as each and every object.then its not plotting . by following method its sets scale i think.
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, nil]];

Comment: If all of the data points are exactly the same, the plot ranges will end up with zero length. You'll need to check the `xRange` and `yRange` after you scale the ranges and adjust them as needed so your data remains visible in all situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Exactly we have to set min max bounds  according to our values.

```
    CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat xMax = 40.0f;  //i need 40 plots 
    CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yMax = 300.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];
```